# Demeteorized app - error on "npm install"

Tags: node.js, macos, meteor, demeteorizer

After demeteorizing my App. The project has a dependency on fibers 1.0.5 and errors out during installation.

I am on Mac OSX Yosemite, node V 4.0.0

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:132:44: error: too many arguments to function call, expected at
most 2, have 4
return Signature::New(isolate, receiver, argc, argv);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../.node-gyp/4.0.0/include/node/v8.h:4675:3: note: 'New' declared
here
static Local New(
^
../src/fibers.cc:140:3: error: no member named 'SetResourceConstraints' in
namespace 'v8'; did you mean simply 'SetResourceConstraints'?
v8::SetResourceConstraints(isolate, constraints);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
SetResourceConstraints
../src/fibers.cc:139:7: note: 'SetResourceConstraints' declared here
void SetResourceConstraints(Isolate* isolate, ResourceConstraint...
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.../Meteor/boldvueDeploy/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm v2.14.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: node ./build.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: demeteorizing package is old I wouldn't recommend on using it anymore try mup for deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having fibers problems too whilst deploying to ubuntu 14.04 using mup. It turned out to be the nodejs version, I tried to user the 0.10.40 version and it worked!

I would suggest you to use mup. Install it by using

```
npm install -g mup
```

On your project directory run this command:

```
mup init
```

It will create two files mup.json and settings.json

Change the node version on mup.json to "0.10.40" like this:

```
"nodeVersion": "0.10.40"
```

Run:

```
mup setup
```

And then:

```
mup deploy
```

And your project should be up and running.

Visit https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

Comment: Thank you for this João Victor.  I indeed moved over to mup and it has served me very well!